# Is it possible to run a while loop and check for tkinter input in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, tkinter

I have the following code, which is a much simplified version of another program, but i can't get the tkinter window buttons to respond, and so was wondering if it was possible to get the `bck` and `nxt`
functions to call on button press and not just at the start, yet still execute the run loop. I would also like to know, if it is possible, if it is possible to modify a variable in a function, which is run on tkinter button press, but be able to use the modified variable outside of that function. Thanks in advance.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

def nxt(count):
    print("Forward", (count+1))
def bck(count):
    print("Back", (count-1))

def run(count, root):
    while True:
        count+=0.1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(count)
        root.update()
        if count==100:
            break

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100-0+0")
count=0

fwd=tk.Button(root, text="Next", command=nxt(count)).pack()
bck=tk.Button(root, text="Previous", command=bck(count)).pack()

root.update()
run(count, root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=` expects "function name" - it means name without `()` and `arguments`.

Now Python call your functions `nxt(count)` and `bck(count)` and assign to `command=` values returned by this functions. Sometimes it is usefull.

But you need something different.

```
command=lambda:nxt(count)
```

`lambda` create function without arguments - and you can assign it to `command=`.

---

**BTW:** using `sleep` and `while True` in Tkinter (and in any other GUI frameworks - like PyQt, wxPython) is not good solution. It can stop `mainloop()` to do its job - handle events, update widgets, redraw widgets.

(probably all GUI frameworks has `mainloop` or something similar)

---

**EDIT:** don't use the same name `bck` for function name (`def bck(...)`) and button name (`bck = Button(...)`)

-

This line

```
fwd = Widget(...).pack()
```

will assign `None` to `fwd` because `pack()` returns `None`

use

```
fwd = Widget(...)
fwd.pack()
```

or - if you don't need variable `fwd`

```
Widget(...).pack()
```

---

Code with `root.after` instead of `while True`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def nxt(count):
    print("Forward:", count)

def bck(count):
    print("Back:", count-1)

def run(count, root):

    count += 0.1
    print(count)
    if count < 100:
        # run again after 100ms 
        root.after(100, run, count, root)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100-0+0")
count = 0

fwd_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Next", command=lambda:nxt(count))
fwd_btn.pack()
bck_btn=tk.Button(root, text="Previous", command=lambda:bck(count))
bck_btn.pack()

# first time run immediately
run(count, root)

# or after 100ms
#root.after(100, run, count, root)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to change `count` in `nxt/bck` you will need `global` instead of function argument or class with `self.`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def nxt():
    global count

    count += 1

    print("Forward:", count)

def bck():
    global count

    count -= 1

    print("Back:", count)

def run():
    global count

    count += 0.1

    print(count)

    if count < 100:
        # run again after 100ms 
        root.after(100, run)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100-0+0")
count = 0

# ntxt/bck without arguments because you need `global`
tk.Button(root, text="Next", command=nxt).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Previous", command=bck).pack()

run() # without arguments because you need `global`

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way is to make count a class instance variable/object so it can be accessed throughout the class.  Note that the nxt and bck call in the buttons command call. command=nxt() means call the function when the button is created, command=nxt means call the function when the button is pressed.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x


class IncrementVar():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.count=0
        self.label=tk.Label(root, text=self.count)
        self.label.pack(side="top")

        tk.Button(root, text="Next", command=self.nxt).pack()
        tk.Button(root, text="Previous", command=self.bck).pack()


    def nxt(self):
        self.count += 1
        print("     Forward", self.count)
        self.label.config(text=self.count)

    def bck(self):
        self.count -= 1
        print("     Back", self.count)
        self.label.config(text=self.count)

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100-0+0")
IV=IncrementVar(root)
root.mainloop()
```